# XCode Server git repository path

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

In an XCode post-action script, how can I access the path to the git repository?  Is there a variable available or do I have to dig around and find the absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem, I ended up doing the following:

```
cd ${PROJECT_DIR};GIT_LOG=`git log --no-merges --oneline --since=1.day`
```

The variable PROJECT_DIR is what I was looking for.